# Kotlin - What does companion object fun do?

Tags: android, function, kotlin, companion-object, kotlin-companion

Declaring a "*static*" function in Kotlin is done using:

```
companion object {
    fun classFoo() {
        //do something
    }
}
```

However I was mistakenly coding

```
companion object fun classFoo() {
     //do something
}
```

Expecting the code to do the same, if only one static function was required.

The compiler doesn't argue about that, and it seems to be valid as the compiler expects a `fun` name and parameters. But I never found how to call that function from other class.

What does that form of `companion object fun` do? there is no doc available about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Test {
    companion object fun classFoo() {
        //do something
    }
}
```

is equivalent to

```
class Test {
    companion object // Add "{ }" to make it explicit that the object body is empty

    fun classFoo() {
        //do something
    }
}
```

i.e. a class with an empty companion object (which is valid syntax) and a normal member function, callable in the usual way:

```
Test().classFoo()
```